# Checking directory name with MySQL data (PHP/HTML)

Tags: php, mysql

I have an html table that lists the various folders in a directory using `PHP`. The folder names are an abbreviation of the full name of a company. I'm calling `MySQL` in order to access the database that holds the key between the company abbreviation (`$comp_id`) and the company name (`$short_name`). Everything works except when I try to check the `$comp_id` with the name of the directory (which is the same), in order to print the `short_name` into the table. Here's what I have:

```
$myDirectory = opendir(".");

$blacklist = array(".", ".."); 

while(false !== ($entryName = readdir($myDirectory))) {
    if (!in_array($entryName, $blacklist)) {
        $dirArray[] = $entryName;
    }
}

closedir($myDirectory);
$indexCount = count($dirArray);

if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($comp_id, $short_name);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        //printf("%s, %s\n", $comp_id, $short_name);
        //echo("<br>");
    }
    $stmt->close();
}

echo ("<TABLE border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 class= whitelinks>\n");
echo ("<TR><TH>CheckBox</TH><th>File Name</th><th>Company Name</th></TR>\n");

for ($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
    if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != ".") {  
            echo("<TR><TD><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"comp[]\" value=\"$dirArray[$index]\"</td>");
            echo("<td>");
            echo("<a href=\"$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a></td>");
            if ($comp_id = $dirArray[$index]){
                echo("<td>");
                echo($short_name);      
                echo("</td>");
                }
            echo("</TR>\n");
            }   
        }

echo("</TABLE>\n");
```

It's echoing the last possible `$short_name` and not the corresponding company name of the directory.

I'm new to `php`, so this is probably an obvious and rookie mistake.

Comment: I don't see where you load values into `$dirArray[]` array.  or where you set `$indexCount` ....this looks incomplete

Comment: @RightClick Sorry, left it out when I posted it. Should be there now

Comment: If you're using a prepared statement you neet to either use `bindParam()` or pass the parameters into the `execute()` statement. If you're not using a prepared statement, use `$con->query($sql)` instead of `prepare()`... doen't matter tho since that block doesn't do anything..

Comment: for each iteration through the for loop at the bottom (where you loop through the folder) you need to get the long name for that short name. So you can write a function that does the query each time, or load it into an associative array up top and then get the values back out....but right now you're not going to get the long names in the bottom loop like that

Comment: I just explained it a little better in an answer.  It's really tough to test without your db, but there are just 2 parts, a couple lines to try out and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//make an associative array to hold values
$longNames=array();

if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($comp_id, $short_name);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        //printf("%s, %s\n", $comp_id, $short_name);
        //echo("<br>");

        //in query, load array using comp_id as key
        $longNames[$comp_id]=$short_name;


    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

at the bottom, you have the same $comp_id inside of your loop, because you named the folders using those ids, right?

So in that last for loop,

```
$comp_id = $dirArray[$index];
$short_name= $lonhNames[$comp_id];

echo "$comp_id , $short_name <br />\r\n";
```

so the complete code would be something like this...

```
$myDirectory = opendir(".");

$blacklist = array(".", ".."); 

while(false !== ($entryName = readdir($myDirectory))) {
    if (!in_array($entryName, $blacklist)) {
        $dirArray[] = $entryName;
    }
}

closedir($myDirectory);
$indexCount = count($dirArray);

//new array here for matching short/long names
$longNames=array();

if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($comp_id, $short_name);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        //printf("%s, %s\n", $comp_id, $short_name);
        //echo("<br>");
//in query, load array using comp_id as key
            $longNames[$comp_id]=$short_name;

    }
    $stmt->close();
}

echo ("<TABLE border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 class= whitelinks>\n");
echo ("<TR><TH>CheckBox</TH><th>File Name</th><th>Company Name</th></TR>\n");

for ($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
    if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != ".") {  
            echo("<TR><TD><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"comp[]\" value=\"$dirArray[$index]\"</td>");
            echo("<td>");
            echo("<a href=\"$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a></td>");

                echo("<td>");
                echo($longNames[$dirArray[$index]]);      
                echo("</td>");

            echo("</TR>\n");
            }   
        }

echo("</TABLE>\n");
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd still put the last part, `$comp_id = $dirArray[$index]:` and so on , under an if statement right? To ensure that the new `$short_name` matches with the proper directory name?

Comment: no, we're using the $comp_id as an id, it's the key to the array.  this line `echo($longNames[$dirArray[$index]]);` says, get the value from the array for this $comp_id, so if that comp_id/short_name combo was together in your table, they got put together in your array, and when you call the array using that key you'll get the matching value.

Comment: from my understanding, the $comp_id is the same as the folder name, and the $short_name is something longer that might contain some characters you can't use to name folders...so they'll never be the same.  Hence why you need a table and query to get the $short_names rather than just using `readdir` and being done with it

Comment: Yep, that's how it works. One thing that I should clarify though is that for all the companies listed with `mysql`, there may or may not be a folder for the company yet in the directory. As for the code, it seems like everything should be perfect. Not sure why i'm getting an undefined index error with `echo($longNames[$dirArray[$index]]);`

Comment: you're in a loop that is going through all of your folder names.  One of those folder names doesn't have an entry in the table, so it never got put into the array.  Let's say for example it's named "folder1".  Since the folder was there, it tries $longNames["folder1"], but that was never set, because it wasn't queried from the table.  So that index (folder1) is undefined.  You can prevent this by checking if the index is set first, with this if.... `if (array_key_exists ( $dirArray[$index] , $longNames))`

Comment: then inside that if you can put `$longNames[$dirArray[$index]]` and it won't get called unless it's in the array

Answer (score 0):

You have this

```
  if ($comp_id = $dirArray[$index]){
```

And it need to be this

```
  if ($comp_id == $dirArray[$index]){
```

You are missing one =

Comment: Thanks! Tried this, but it's not showing anything for company name now

Comment: I am not sure but this is not good

if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query))  again you have only one = in the if statement

Comment: That's actually fine. That code assigns the result of the function to the variable, and checks that the result evaluates to a truthy value.

Comment: Can you print what the query is returning when executed I am not sure where do they end up when you close connection put them in some variable before closing

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is using an assignment operator when I believe you are tyring to use a comparison operator.

Try changing
`if ($comp_id = $dirArray[$index])`

To:
`if ($comp_id == $dirArray[$index])`

Comment: Thanks! Tried this but it's not showing anything for company name now

Comment: Do you mean `$short_name` is printing nothing on the page, or that you are no longer getting `<td>`s either?

Because if you are no longer getting `<td>`s, that would indicate your condition is failing. If that is the case, check to be sure `$short_name` is being properly populated.

If you don't have access to the query, try printing `$short_name` somewhere readable, or passing it through `gettype()`, described here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php

Comment: `short_name` isn't printing anything. Sorry, should've been more specific

Comment: If `$short_name` is displaying nothing, you should check that it is being properly populated. Try printing it somewhere, or passing it through `gettype()`, described here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php